# Keep getting error in JavaFX every time I try to add an image. java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java

For the past couple of days, I have tried everything to get an image on JavaFx. And no matter what I try it's always the same error. It's always the same error no matter what I do. This error only occurs with images. When I use a try-catch the exception I get printed out is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found.

```
 package application;

 import java.io.FileInputStream;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

 import javafx.application.Application;
 import javafx.geometry.Pos;
 import javafx.scene.Group;
 import javafx.scene.Scene;
 import javafx.scene.control.Label;
 import javafx.scene.image.Image;
 import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
 import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
 import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
 import javafx.scene.text.Font;
 import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
 import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Practice extends Application {
     public void start(Stage stage) throws FileNotFoundException {         
      //Creating an image 
      Image image = new Image(new 
FileInputStream("Users/user/Documents/Minesweeper/1.png"));  

      //Setting the image view 
      ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image); 

      //Setting the position of the image 
      imageView.setX(50); 
      imageView.setY(25); 

      //setting the fit height and width of the image view 
      imageView.setFitHeight(455); 
      imageView.setFitWidth(500); 

      //Setting the preserve ratio of the image view 
      imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);  

      //Creating a Group object  
      Group root = new Group(imageView);  

      //Creating a scene object 
      Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 500);  

      //Setting title to the Stage 
      stage.setTitle("Loading an image");  

      //Adding scene to the stage 
      stage.setScene(scene);

      //Displaying the contents of the stage 
      stage.show(); 
   }  
   public static void main(String args[]) { 
      launch(args); 
   }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Check you path to the image file. The path `"Users/user/Documents/Minesweeper/1.png"` is a relative path, ensure the directory above `Users` is your present working directory.

Otherwise you can put the absolute path to your image as argument to `FileInputStream`.

Simple java file structure should be like:

```
WorkingDir
    |
    ----application
    |            |
    |            ----Practice.java
    |----1.png
```

With this structure, you will be able to load you image as

```
Image image = new Image(new FileInputStream("1.png"));
```